# Read a specific portion of a text file in C++ (in between two delimiters)

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a text file in the following format:

`UserIP-Address-1
UserInfo-1
UserInfo-2
UserInfo-3
UserIP-Address-1_ENDS
UserIP-Address-2
UserInfo-1
UserInfo-2
UserInfo-3
UserIP-Address-2-ENDS`

I need to collect information as per client request and send the data in between these two `UserIP-Address-1` and `UserIP-Address-1_ENDS` delimiters. I can find one of the delimiters using `find` or `vector::iterator`, but how to find another end and data in between? Please guide me, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should define (at least on paper or in comments) *precisely* the format of your file, perhaps thru some [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) notation. An example is never enough (and better then, in addition of the format documentation, gives some real concrete example, not abstract ones). If the file is produced by some other software, that software should document the format.

You need to read the file line by line (e.g. using [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)), and probably entirely (or at least till you have gotten all the wanted information). You might use standard [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques (probably on every line, perhaps on the entire file as a whole). You could (at least if the file is not very large) fill some data in memory.

If the file is really big (e.g. gigabytes which does not fit in RAM), you could read it twice. The first time, to compute offsets (using [tellg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/basic_istream/tellg/)) of relevant lines (or data chunks), e.g. into some `std::map` and the second time to use [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/basic_istream/seekg/) appropriately to read portions of that file.

If you can change the format of the file, you could consider using standard textual serialization formats like [JSON](http://json.org/) (which has several C++ libraries handling it, e.g. [JSONCPP](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)) or [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) (I don't recommend XML, unless it is an external requirement, since XML is too complex and too verbose). You might also consider some database approach, perhaps as simple as [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/).

Comment: sir, the file is around `10MB`

Comment: 10MB fits in RAM very easily (unless your computer is a cheap embedded microcontroller), at least on desktops, laptops and tablets.

Comment: yes so `getline` will be sufficient and while reading each line I will just use `std::find` for these two delimiters and a `std::vector` to `push_back` those lines?

Comment: Yes, something like that. You obviously should define *precisely* your input format.